# Hi, I am try to upgrade one of egg to python 3.11 (migrated in poetry) from python 3.7 but I faces following error

Tags: fixtures, python-3.11

@pytest.fixture
def http_client(io_loop):
E       fixture 'io_loop' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: anyio_backend, anyio_backend_name, anyio_backend_options, app, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, cli_runner, cov, doctest_namespace, http_client, loop, monkeypatch, no_cover, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, register_key, register_key_values, register_key_with_different_versions, result_data, sanic_client, spec_int, spec_int_values, test_client, test_data, test_int, test_int_values, test_result, test_server, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, unused_port, verbase_obj
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```

Is there need to add any another package to solve the error?